# FogBugz Screenshot does not start up at boot

Tags: screenshot, fogbugz

Some of our FogBugz users experience that the Screenshot tool does not start-up automatically at boot. The quickest work-around is to re-install it. Any ideas on what causes this to happen? And how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Try asking at http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you repost this on fogbugz.stackexchange.com, make sure you specify your OS.